# How to print multiple lists together?

Tags: python, list

Is there a way to print out 2 lists together, for one I can do for

```
for g in grades:
    print(g)
```

Which results in: 83, 25, 90 etc.. I have a second list called 'cc'. Both lists have the same number of items in the proper order. I'm trying to print them as

```
print(cc[0])
print(g[0])
```

And so on for all the items in the list.

I've already tried

```
for g in grades:
    for x in cc:
        print(x)
        print(g)
```

Which as expected prints out many more times than once for each. Is there a way to properly do this? I think I'm writing this clear enough.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the two lists have the same length, you can use `zip`.

`zip` creates a tuple of the successive items in each sequence. `g, x` *"unpacks"* 
 this tuple; that is assign the respective values to `g` and `x`.

```
for x, g in zip(cc, grades):
    print(x, g, end='\n')
```

Comment: Yes, good point, thanks.

Comment: You have enough reputation to find and VTC these excessively basic questions as duplicates, do you still feel it'd be better to answer them?

Answer (score 0):

You can use index function:

```
list1 = ['a','b','c']
list2 = [0,1,2]

for i in list1:
    print(i)
    print(list2[list1.index(i)])
```

**Updated (thanks for @juanpa.arrivillaga):**

But it's a bad solution because it has quadratic-time algorithm. It's better to use enumerate:

```
for index, item in enumerate(list1):
    print(item)
    print(list2[index])
```

Comment: You now have a quadratic-time algorithm. Don't use `list1.index`, rather, *enumerate* list1, so `for i, e in enumerate(list1):`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga thanks!

Comment: Just remember, `my_list.count` and `my_list.index` are O(n). They are very fast and efficient if you do them outside a loop, but inside a loop, they can kill the runtime of your algorithm!